# UITableView disclosure button bug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

When the user click on the disclosure button I perform a segue that push a new view

controller to the current navigation controller. the problem is when I pop the pushed

controller to get to the UITableView I found that the disclosure button is still in dark

blue!!! `see attached image.`

[image]

Comment: Is the tableView inside a UITableViewController?

Comment: yes it is inside UITableViewController

Comment: do you perform the segue in code, on the button's IBAction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tryig with this, hope it will helps you.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the cell is selected.  The selected state is not cleared by default.  Add to `viewWillAppear` method:

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];
```

depending on what you named your tableView property.

Comment: thanks but I did that before and it is already commented in my code now as it does not resolve the problem.